# External monitor (HDMI) not working through USB-C Thuderbolt

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, usb-c, external

I've been using my HP Spectre x360 (i3-ap0044tu) laptop for a few years now and I've been struggling with connecting my external monitor through USB-C.

The external HDMI monitor only receives the signal half the time. When it works, it works pretty well. But when it doesn't work, it doesn't even receive monitor signal. When I plug the USB-C converter in, the laptop screen blinks and so does the external display, but after a while the external display goes back to saying that no signal was found. Sometimes when it doesn't receive any signal, I unplug and plug the cable again, and it works. But this case is rare because most of the time this re-plugging won't work.

I'm using Windows 10 Build 1909. I've blocked further build upgrades because my laptop's drivers cannot support future Windows versions.

I've read somewhere that if you hard reset your laptop by holding the power button, the external monitor will work on next boot. This only worked once for my laptop. Also, the USB-C hub that came with my laptop seems to be doing just fine, so I think no issues there.

I scoured around the web and device manager and tried everything I could. I uninstalled and reinstalled monitor and graphics card drivers but it didn't work. I tried troubleshooting these devices and it didn't work.

If there's anybody who can help me with this frustrating issue, I'd be really happy.

Comment: You could try another adapter for USB-C to HDMI, or another HDMI cable.

Comment: Is your USB-C to HDMI adapter a standard HDMI alt mode adapter, or is it a proprietary "Display**Link**" (note: not Display**Port**) adapter? Also, do you plug it directly into your laptop, or do you plug it into your USB-C hub? Also, is your adapter's HDMI  connector female, or male?

Comment: @harrymc was actually thinking about it for a while. I think I'm finally going to order another adapter.

Comment: @Spiff I'm not sure whether it's a standard or proprietary displaylink adapter, all I know is that this is an USB-C hub from HP. I got this adapter with the laptop. It's got a male USB-C which forks into one female HDMI, one USB-A, and one USB-C port which also supports PD.
I've noticed some changes in the way the external screen blinks when I connect the hub first and then the HDMI cable of the monitor versus when the HDMI cable is already connected to the hub and then I plug the male USB-C of the hub into my laptop. But the results largely remain the same.

Comment: @shady0042 If you post the make and model of the USB-C hub with the integrated HDMI adapter, I can try to look up its specs to see if it uses the standard "HDMI alt mode" provision of USB-C, or if it's the crappy proprietary "DisplayLink" technology.

Comment: @Spiff This is the link I found from HP's website. This is the exact hub I've got: https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-usb-c-to-multi-port-hub/15241795/manuals
Hope this helps. And thanks for helping me out!